# IE9 form with POST method.. Not submitting data on first submit

Tags: php, html, forms, post, internet-explorer-9

I have a simple form with a few inputs containing escaped XML data.  When I submit the form (only with IE9), the data is not sent on the first try; however, if I hit the browser back button and submit again the POST data is sent.  Any ideas?  Below is the form:

```
<form id="bundleOrderInfo" action="/catalog/bundleSubmit" method="POST" ENCTYPE="utf-8" style=""> 
<input type="text" name="requestForHidden" id="requestForHidden" value="SOMEVALUE">
<input type="text" name="itemName" id="itemName" value="SOME SERVICE VALUE">
<input type="text" name="optionNames" id="optionNames" value="DB Modification||Operational Readiness||Server Capacity Adjustment||Storage Capacity Adjustment||Connectivity Enablement||Security Alignment||">          
<input type="text" id="userSelections" name="userSelections" type="text">
<input type="text" id="overallOptions" name="overallOptions" type="text" value='&lt;form&gt;&lt;label id="opt1"&gt;(1) DB Modification&lt;/label&gt;&lt;checkbox readonly="false" label="(1) Operational Readiness" id="opt2" &gt;true&lt;/checkbox&gt;&lt;checkbox readonly="false" label="(1) Server Capacity Adjustment" id="opt3" &gt;true&lt;/checkbox&gt;&lt;checkbox readonly="false" label="(1) Storage Capacity Adjustment" id="opt4" &gt;true&lt;/checkbox&gt;&lt;checkbox readonly="false" label="(1) Connectivity Enablement" id="opt5" &gt;true&lt;/checkbox&gt;&lt;checkbox readonly="false" label="(1) Security Alignment" id="opt6" &gt;true&lt;/checkbox&gt;&lt;/form&gt;'>


<input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
```

Comment: You probably have a problem in your code using IE hit F12 and then start debugging this will let you know if there are javascript errors.

Answer (score -2):

Try changing the submit value from:
 value="Submit"

To:
 value = "send"

or use lower case S in submit

Hope this helps!

Comment: nope, I tried both and that gave me the same behavior with each (ie no post data on the first send, but then when I clicked the browser back button and sent it again, it was there).  Its really weird because it isnt doing it with Firefox